# ¿Como puedo convertir un archivo COM a un EXE?

Tags: exe, com

Tengo entendido que no puedo convertir un archivo EXE a un COM, porque sería como tratar de meter el agua de una bañera en una botella. Pero, ¿es posible al reves (COM => EXE)?

Gracias y saludos

Comment: ¿¿ Para que querría alguien meter un `.com` de hace 30 años en un `.exe` de hace 30 años también ?? ¿¿ Que esperas conseguir con eso ??

Comment: @Trauma Vea pues. Hasta ahora me entero que ya no se usan los `.exe`. Será borrar todos esos archivos en `System32` que ya no se usan :P

Comment: @Alfabravo Se llaman igual, pero **no son lo mismo**. Un `.exe` actual usa el formato `Portable Ejecutable`, mientras que los `.exe` antiguos usan el formato `MZ`. Solo se parecen en la extensión.

Comment: @Trauma Es válido pero nada de eso está en la pregunta. La respuesta pasa por ponerle a usar alguna herramienta de DOS y que lo corra en modo de compatibilidad.

Comment: @Alfabravo Yo no he respondido a nada. En mi primer comentario me limité a interrogar al autor por el objetivo de semejante cosa, puesto que me parece algo poco útil hoy día. Sospecho que la base de su planteamiento puede ser erróneo. Luego me he limitado a contestarte a tí :-)

Comment: Esstoy intentando crear un programa en Python que coge unas instrucciones definidas por mi y las convierte en un EXE

Comment: Python para transformar el COM? Seguro no es un BAT?

Comment: Primero escribo el programa. Después el programa de Python lo escribe en ASM. Y después se compila en COM. El problema es que COM no es compatible con x64 y yo tengo x86.

Comment: @ByRussX Yo te diría que busques un ensamblador que sea capaz de generar código `.exe`. Seguro que las herramientas de GNU te pueden servir.

Comment: Si, el problema es que no he encontrado ningún sitio donde aprender a programar `.exe`. Yo solo se `.com` :(

Comment: Claro, porque el `.com` tiene el mecanismo de un chupete :-) De todas formas, el ensamblador se debe de encargar de esos detalles, aunque tengas que utilizar una herramienta extra (un enlazador), tu código *asm* no debería de tener que cambiar mucho ... siempre y cuando **no uses** llamadas al sistema. ¿ Que estás haciendo, llamadas a `int21h` ?

Comment: Si, todo depende de la instruccion en Python

Comment: Pero lo que estoy haciendo no tiene ningun uso util

Comment: Lo hago para entretenerme

Comment: Es como crear un compilador de un lenguaje que no existe :-)

Comment: No escribas tantos comentarios sueltos, que nos llamaran la atención. El problema de usar la `int21h` es que solo existía en MS-DOS, los sistemas modernos lo *emulan* en el modo compatibilidad. Si insistes en usarla, pues solo podras generar `.exe` de los antiguos, en formato `MZ`. Puedes usar una herramienta (si la encuentras) que convierta de .com -> .exe. O tendras que cambiar las herramientas que usas. Usar un enlazador no es mas que un paso mas. O buscar doc sobre el formato .MZ y generar tu mismo el .exe. Eso si será divertido :-)

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113521/discussion-between-byruss-x-and-trauma).